# Editing a variable inside of a script with sed

Tags: sed, bash

Perhaps I'm stetching bash a bit far, but I have this variable containing a list of urls.

```
#!/bin/bash    
/* returns
/path/page/one.php
/path/subseciton/
/path/to/this/section/
/path/to/yet/aother_section/about.php
etc
*/
list_of_urls = $(pull_urls.sh)
```

Then I have a for loop running, pulling text content from the old server and the new server. On each of those I'm running various diff commands to see what has changed.

```
for i in $urls
    do

        echo $i
        storage_area=./working/$i/
        mkdir -p $storage_area


        xidel http://oldserver/$i  -e '//div[@id="maincontent"]//p' > $storage_area/old.txt
        xidel http://newserver/$i -e '//div[@id="content"]//p' > $storage_area/new.txt
        diff $storage_area/old.txt $storage_area/new.txt > $storage_area/diff.diff
        wdiff $storage_area/old.txt $storage_area/new.txt > $storage_area/wdiff.wdiff
    done
```

My problem is that I need to remove a trailing slash. Is it advisable to do so in the following way?

```
// inside the loop, before xidel calls
i=$(echo $i | sed -e 's/\/$//g')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about in this way:

```
kent$ i=foo/                                                                                                                                             
kent$ i=${i%/}                                                                                                                                           
kent$ echo $i
foo
```

if you prefer doing it with `sed`, you could consider to use another separator other than `/`, since you want to use slash in your pattern:

```
kent$ i=/path/to/this/section/
kent$ i=$(sed 's#/$##'<<<"$i")
kent$ echo $i
/path/to/this/section
```

Comment: Thank you. About to mark as correct once time limit expires. Would you mind explaining how and why {%/} this works? What is that called? Or, which man page should I read? Again, thank you!

Comment: @Richard click here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: if you prefer to read man page, `man bash` and search `Parameter Expansion`